# X, Y are inner-product space A is a mapping from X to Y, and ||Ax-Ay||=||x-y|| and A0=0, how to prove A is a linear operator??

Tags: inner-products

It seems not easy for proving.

As we know, ||Ax||_Y=||x||_X, then A preserves the distance, but how to use this condition to prove A is a linear operator? I feel confused.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $$
\langle A(u),A(u)\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle \quad\forall u\in X
$$
For $x,y\in X$, let $v = A(x+y)-A(x)-A(y)$, and compute
$$
\langle v,v\rangle
$$
repeatedly using the above property.

Comment: I compute as you said, while I can not obtain <v,v>=0 just using the property you referred. Terms such as <A(x+y),Ax> etc, these cross terms can not be dealed. Could you please make it more specific? Thank you.

Comment: You also need the Polarization identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) to tell you that $$\langle A(u),A(v)\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle \quad\forall u,v\in X $$

Comment: Thank you vvvvery much, I got it!!!